# Filter method not working correctly in react/redux, typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Can't figure out why filter method in reducer “showCurImg" not working correctly.
I am trying to filter my state "gallery" which is array of objects, where objects contain File(image uploaded by user) and id and it should return me object with id, but return empty array.

If for example i change my filter function with '!==', it returns me array with "proxy objects" inside. What’s wrong with my code?

This is my slice

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { RootState } from "../../app/store";

export interface imgItem {
  imgItem: File;
  id: number;
}

export interface imgs {
  preview: imgItem[];
  gallery: imgItem[];
  curImg: {};
}

const initialState: imgs = {
  preview: [],
  gallery: [],
  curImg: {},
};

export const imgsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userImgs",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    previewImgs: (state, action: PayloadAction<imgItem[]>) => {
      state.preview = action.payload;
    },
    cleanPreview: (state) => {
      state.preview = [];
    },
    addToGallery: (state, action: PayloadAction<imgItem[]>) => {
      state.gallery = [...state.gallery, ...action.payload];
    },
    showCurImg: (state, action: PayloadAction<Number>) => {
      const gal = state.gallery;
      const filteredArray = gal.filter((item) => item.id === action.payload);
      console.log(filteredArray);
    },
  },
});

export const { previewImgs, addToGallery, cleanPreview, showCurImg } =
  imgsSlice.actions;

export const imgsArr = (state: RootState) => state.getImgs.preview;

export default imgsSlice.reducer;
```

Component where i received files from user

```
import React, { ChangeEvent } from "react";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../app/hooks";
import Preview from "./Preview";
import {
  addToGallery,
  cleanPreview,
  previewImgs,
} from "../features/imgs/imgsSlice";
import styles from "./FormImgs.module.css";

export default function FormImgs() {
  const { preview } = useAppSelector((state) => state.getImgs);

  const changeHandler = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const chosenFiles = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.target.files);
    const res = [];
    for (const item of chosenFiles) {
      const imgId = Math.random();
      res.push({ imgItem: item, id: imgId });
    }
    console.log(res);
    dispatch(previewImgs(res));
  };

  const submitHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addToGallery(preview));
    dispatch(cleanPreview());
    console.log(preview);
  };

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  return (
    <div className={styles.form}>
      <p>Add an amazing photo from your device to your gallery</p>
      <form action="#" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div className={styles.selectBtn}>
          <input
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            multiple
            onChange={changeHandler}
            title="Select images"
            id="select"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
          />
          <label htmlFor="select">Select file</label>
        </div>

        {preview.length ? (
          <>
            <Preview />
            <button type="submit">Add to gallery</button>
          </>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in creating id through Math.random().
I should used "parseFloat" instead "parseInt"